# Linking against XCode dylibs with Python ctypes

Tags: xcode, compilation, ctypes, pyglet, vispy

I am installing [Pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home_) as a dependency for [VisPy](http://vispy.org/) but am seeing the following error after installation

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 160, in load_library

raise ImportError('Library "%s" not found.' % names[0])
ImportError: Library "c" not found.
```

Digging through the source code, I realized that Pyglet is attempting to load the standard C library using the ctypes framework.

Further digging reveals the actual (un-swallowed) error:

```
File   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libc.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libc.dylib: mach-o, but wrong filetype
```

The issue, I think, is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010443/python-libusb-pyusb-mach-o-but-wrong-architecture) where there is an architecture mismatch. The Python C binding framework 'ctypes' is attempting to load a .dylib with the wrong architecture.

Since I have set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to

```
/Applications.../MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/
```

the loader is favoring this directory. However, if I try to load 'libc.dylib' from the standard location `/usr/lib` everything works perfectly.

The obvious potential problem is that the XCode version of 'libc' is for the 32-bit architecture but the `/usr/lib` is for the 64-bit architecture.

**Not true!**

Here is the output of `file` for both libraries:

XCode version

```
libc.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
libc.dylib (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library stub x86_64
libc.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library stub i386
```

and the standard in `/usr/lib`

```
/usr/lib/libc.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/lib/libc.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit  dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/usr/lib/libc.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

*The only difference is that the XCode version is a "stub"*. Despite some googling, the difference is not entirely clear, though it appears that the difference between a "stub" dylib and a "non-stub" is what is causing the problem.

A bit more information about my setup:

```
/usr/bin/python : Python 2.7.10 and appears to be running as a 64-bit app
uname -a: Darwin x-10-104-106-204.uofm-secure.wireless.umn.edu 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

My question is thus *how does one properly link against the dylibs installed by XCode*?

Thanks in advance for all ideas and suggestions.